# Jquery "does not recognize" variable in `name`

Tags: jquery

Example is here https://jsfiddle.net/69k05rvt/2/

On page load creates variable `current_tab_name` and assign `current_tab_name = 'sales_quote';`

Also on page load creates input field `<input name="' + current_tab_name + '_product_name" type="text" value="" />`

After i click on `<span id="sales_invoice">Invoice</span>`, assign `current_tab_name = 'sales_invoice';`. And creates another input field that looks like: `<input name="sales_invoice_product_name" type="text" value="">`.

Why for `sales_quote` this `$( document ).on( 'keyup', 'input[name*="' + current_tab_name + '_product_name"]', function() {`  works, but for `sales_invoice` does not work. If in https://jsfiddle.net/69k05rvt/2/ i type something in first input field, all works, but if i type in second input field,- does not work.

Here is whole code:

```html
<span id="sales_invoice">Invoice</span>
<div id="gsg_sales_quote"></div> 
<div id="gsg_sales_invoice"></div>
```

```js
var current_tab_name = "";
if (current_tab_name === "") {
  current_tab_name = "sales_quote";
}

$(document).on("click", "#sales_invoice ", function () {
  //current_tab_name = $(this).attr('id').trim();
  current_tab_name = "sales_invoice";
  add_first_group_of_goods_services();
  //console.log( 'current_tab_name ' + typeof current_tab_name + ' / ' + current_tab_name );
});

function add_first_group_of_goods_services() {
  //console.log('inside function add_first_group_of_goods_services ' + current_tab_name);
  var new_goods_services = $(document.createElement("div"));
  new_goods_services
    .after()
    .html(
      '<input name="' +
        current_tab_name +
        '_product_name" type="text" value="" />'
    );
  new_goods_services.appendTo("#gsg_" + current_tab_name);
}
add_first_group_of_goods_services();

$(document).on("keyup", function () {
  console.log(
    "current_tab_name:" +
      current_tab_name +
      " / Keyup $(this).attr(name):" +
      $(this).attr("name")
  );
});

$(document).on(
  "keyup",
  'input[name*="' + current_tab_name + '_product_name"]',
  function () {
    console.log(
      "current_tab_name:" +
        current_tab_name +
        " / With var $(this).attr(name):" +
        $(this).attr("name")
    );
  }
);

$(document).on(
  "keyup",
  'input[name*="sales_invoice_product_name"]',
  function () {
    console.log(
      "current_tab_name:" +
        current_tab_name +
        " / Without var $(this).attr(name):" +
        $(this).attr("name")
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Consider `var a = "a"; var b = "b" + a; a = "c";`. What is the value of `b`? The second _selector_ parameter to `.on()` is only evaluated once, just like `b` is in the previous example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set an event using `on()` with the variable `current_tab_name`, it will be set to whatever string is set at runtime. In the JSfiddle, that will always be `sales_quote_product_name`. If you set the following

```js
if( current_tab_name === '' ){ 
current_tab_name = 'sales_invoice';
}
```

All three events will trigger.

The `input[name*="' + current_tab_name + '_product_name"]` event will not update with any changes to `current_tab_name` since it is set at runtime. You're better off just setting a class to the element and then checking if the name matches like this.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".tab-input", function(data){
    if ($(this).attr("name") == "sales_quote_product_name"){
        console.log("Fire sales quote");
    }else if ($(this).attr("name") == "sales_invoice_product_name"){
        console.log("First sales invoice");
    }
});
```

Edit: You should probably use data attributes instead of the name attribute. E.g.

```html
<input type="text" class="tab-input" data-tab="sales-invoice">
<input type="text" class="tab-input" data-tab="sales-quote">
```

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".tab-input", function(data){
    console.log("Tab: " + $(this).data("tab"));
    if ($(this).data("tab") == "sales-quote"){
        console.log("Fire sales quote");
    }else if ($(this).data("tab") == "sales-invoice"){
        console.log("First sales invoice");
    }
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/c4wx3vpb/